# Prevent 36V going through 12V, 30A circuit

Tags: power-supply, high-current

I have to arrange 3 of 12V batteries using a DPDT switch.
Position A: 3 batteries are connected in parallel to supply 12V to devices in my van. 
Position B: 3 batteries are connected in series to provide 36V for welding. 
To insure 36V never go down the 12V line; Is there a way to protect and isolate 36V coming over to 12V line (ex fuse, detector with SSR drivers)? If so, how fast the response time could be?

---

Edit: This is what I have at the moment. The DPDT switches between 36V mode and 12V mode. Please, review if the circuitry can work as I want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe08Oa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A schematic would be helpful, but a second switch on the 12/36V mode control line that also disconnects the battery from the load would probably suit the purpose.

Comment: There's already a second switch to isolate the battery. I'm trying to avoid the "Ooh, what does this switch do?" scenario. Actually, that's why the isolator is labelled the "Becky" switch after my ex mother-in-law.

Comment: Is it really necessary to associate a woman's name with doing something careless? A lot of our readers are women and this seems a bit offensive to me.

Comment: I mean an interlock switch that both isolates the battery and also allows whatever relay setup you have to reconfigure the circuit for 36V operation.

If you're concerned about deliberate tampering, maybe a keyswitch?  Or a fake switch?

Comment: It's named after my ex mother-in-law. We found the 12V system wasn't working in the new RV and were trying to troubleshoot the problem. It was only after I'd sat down and noticed a switch labelled "battery isolator" by the door that she confessed she'd flipped it but it didn't seem to do anything. From then on, it was known as the Becky switch.
(And she thinks it's great!)

Comment: I was kind of looking for an if-all-else fails method so that in a worst case scenario, the over voltage _cannot_ get through. I don't care where it goes, if anywhere, so long as it does not go down the 12V line.

Comment: Hey Mike, any particular reason why you would need all three in parallel? Are you starting the engine with this? I think the solution you are looking for is heavily dependent on the current requirements of the various connected systems, so some more information on the expected loads on this battery of batteries in each mode (parallel/series) would be nice.

Comment: Basically for welding. The high currents involved are too much for 12V but I have found a constant current circuit that can run off 36V that can handle the kind of stuff that I need.

Comment: Edited to add the schematic but I think I've done something wrong. In its switched position, the positive goes to ground. Trying to remember what I did.

Comment: Unless you've mis-drawn, V1 and V3 are permanently in parallel, which defeats your object. Is this something you've built, or something your are trying to build? There was a reason I left all the voltage sources +ve upwards, it makes the circuit easier to 'read' for experienced engineers. Try to do the same, voltage generally increasing as you go up the page.

Comment: Ah, there's a very good reason for that - I have no idea what I'm doing! 40 years ago I drew a few diagrams for my O level physics. I built it with 2 batteries and am working to add a third, I adapted the diagram to use buses whereas I was thinking of terminal to terminal so I'm sure that's where I made the mistake. Experimentation has been pretty hands on rather than theoretical. I'll stick to the + up now that I know - I was just minimising the wiring but the components get priority - got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question should include a basic diagram.

I assume your wiring is something like this:
[image]
Consider having a relay that will only power one of the outputs:
[image]
For the extra peace of mind, add an over voltage protection (MAX6495–MAX6499) between the 12V output and the 12V loads. In case everything else fails, this circuit will protect the 12V loads:
[image]

Comment: Those circuits seem to be rated in milliamps but I'm looking at up to 30A. I'll put together a diagram but how do you represent a 2-position, 6 pin (2 in 1 out) switch?

Comment: not at all, MAX6495–MAX6499 controls a mosfet, the mosfet can handle 30A if you choose the right one.

Comment: Ah, right, I'll see if I can find the right one. I need to re-check my work so far thanks to the circuit diagram I made.

Answer (score 6):

There's no reason your welder and your 12 V supply should share the same terminals.

Whatever the present wiring of your 12/36 switch, it should be possible to rearrange it so that it selects one output connector when on 36 V and the other when on 12 V. If you don't think that's possible, post the present configuration and we'll see. Make the connectors incompatible, and your isolation is assured.

There is a potential problem whenever you disconnect and then later reconnect batteries in parallel, if they have had the opportunity to become unbalanced. A very large current could flow at reconnection.

The best, most flexible scheme I've come up with is this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRShAR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I've shown a fuse on each battery. I've shown these as switches, but you could use relays as well. Switches shown in the 12 V position.

- All switches in the 12 V position - all batteries parallel to 12 V output, no connection to 36 V output.
- All switches to 36 V - 36 V output on, no connection to 12 V.
- Any one switch 12 V -  no connection to 36 V output, that one battery connected to the 12 V output. This is useful for checking, charging or debugging your batteries one by one, without having to access the battery compartment.
- Any other switch configuration - no connection to 36 V output, two batteries paralleled to 12 V output. This allows you to isolate one problematic battery.

There are other arrangements. In particular, it would be quite easy to eliminate one pair of switches, ending up with Raul's answer. However, that's a small saving, and doesn't allow the flexibility that this does.

Amongst the benefits of this arrangement are that any switch can get stuck in either position, and you don't get a dangerous cross connection. Check any other arrangement to make sure it has this fail safe feature.

The only drawback is that if you used 12 V without all switches in the '12 V' position, you would unbalance the batteries, with a hazard when you came to reconnect them. You could use a simple mechanical bar across all their toggles so they would only be normally operated as a unit, and the bar removed for debugging. How often does 'Becky' use the welder? There would be little problem to putting the switches behind a cover that only you get to remove.

A further advantage. When you've finished using the 36 V output, do you just slam the batteries back to 12 V? With good identical batteries, all with the same initial state of charge, after using them in series, they will have very similar final states of charge, and so can be connected safely back in parallel again. However, if that's not the case, you could blow fuses when you reconnect (or worse if you've not included fuses). With this arrangement, you can quickly check the battery voltage one by one (you probably have a system voltmeter anyway, they're pretty cheap if you haven't) before reconnecting as 12 V, and only do so if they're close enough.

Comment: I've simply switched the positive and negative terminals on the middle battery through a 2-way switch, thereby changing them from parallel to series. The terminals of the last battery in the sequence are the same. If there's a better way to do that then I'm open to suggestions. I could, I suppose, do that switch through 2 more relays and have control over the isolate/switch sequence.

Comment: @Mike Post a diagram of what you have at the moment

Comment: Done but it's not quite right. The DPDT switches the polarity of the middle battery but I'm sure I had to do more to it than that, I just can't remember what.

Comment: @Mike updated my answer

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank you so much. I was thinking I'd have to reverse the polarity of the second battery, too. I'm more of a software guy so I'm trying to piece the electronics together from half-remembered O level stuff, other people's examples and experimental results. Learning peacemeal, so to speak.
I appreciate your time and effort in helping me